# Where does The Darkness II keeps its save files?

Tags: the-darkness-2

Say I wanted to back up or delete my saves on the PC version (via Steam).

Where are they located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using X to represent the game installation hard drive, they're in:
`X:\Users\YourUserNameHere\AppData\Roaming\DarknessII`

Once inside that folder, you should see a folder with a random string of digits as the name. Inside is your save.

Comment: You're right, except I recognize the "random" digits as my Steam ID.

Comment: Ahk, I just never memorised my ID, lol.

Comment: I do not have that directory. Do you know where it is in this directory? C:\Users\Username\Documents\Steam\steamapps\common\darkness ii Also the name of the saves files or the extension would help? There are no cloud saves so I am trying to sync with dropbox.

Comment: Which directory don't you have? Asking because if you don't see AppData, it's a hidden folder inside your Account folder. So enable hidden files to appear or just click in the address bar and add it in. If it is the "DarknessII" folder you are missing then I'm not entirely sure where your saves would be located. That's the only place I could find them myself.

Answer (score -3):

For me it wasn't in the AppData folder either.
It was in the standard Windows folder "My Documents" (and there in "Darkness Within 2"). The files are named "savegame1", "savegame2" etc. but have no file extension (so no .loc or .bin etc.).

If you have trouble finding "My Documents", it is in the same folder as AppData.

Comment: "Darkness Within 2" and "The Darkness 2" are not the same game.

Comment: If this is infact being flagged due to being an incorrect answer, please just down vote the answer. An incorrect answer does not equal a low quality answer.