# Where are Darkness 2 Game Saves for Steam?

Tags: the-darkness-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does The Darkness II keeps its save files?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49881/where-does-the-darkness-ii-keeps-its-save-files)

I do not have that directory.

X:\Users\YourUserNameHere\AppData\Roaming\DarknessII

Do you know where it is in this directory?

C:\Users\Username\Documents\Steam\steamapps\common\darkness ii

Also the name of the saves files or the extension would help? There are no cloud saves so I am trying to sync with dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

As I just replied to your comment on the other question. If it's AppData you don't see enable hidden files to be visible or manually add it to the address bar. That is the only place I'm aware the saves exist. The exact name of the save file (or at least for me) is: CONTINUE.SAV